# Swift nested optional value types (structs) and modification of properties

Tags: swift, struct, nested, value-type

I am using several value types in my model and this value types (structs) has as properties nested other value types (structs). Then having root object I want to modify (add, delete, update) property in some of this nested struct inside another structs. Moreover this properties usually have optional types and can be nil. So as value type when assigned to var, let gets copied, I cannot use optional binging of this inner structs instances and modifying them later. So the only way I have to do this modification is like below:

```
if let cleaningDetails = initialPackage?.cleaningsSchedule?.details?[indexPath.row], cleaningDetails.startTimes == nil {
                        initialPackage?.cleaningsSchedule?.details?[indexPath.row].startTimes = []
                    }
```

So it is really the only option when using value types. What are other solutions? Change to classes (reference types) - here is this functional, value-type programming really that great? Or should I just use more mutating functions on this struct to facilitate modifications?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here, and I suspect you're over-using optionals. It is very rarely sensible to have an optional Array (or other Collection, including String). Just make the default value `[]` rather than `nil` and get rid of the optionals. The fact that you are replacing `nil` with `[]` suggests that `nil` and `[]` are really the same thing. (Whenever that's true, you shouldn't use an Optional.)

Comment: This arrays, strings are defined as properties of model struct that is decoded  from web api response, and many times this field may be not available. And optionals are the only way to enable this models to be flexible when working with JSONDecoder. I try to modify this objects and then resent them to web api. For me this optional chaining seems a little cumbersome and I am asking whether it is the only solution to modify such objects.

Comment: `JSONDecoder` can avoid this. You can implement a `init(from:)` method that assigns empty values and doesn't need Optionals, and you can implement an `encode` method that removes empty values if you need that too. JSON-compatibility issues should not be allowed to spread through your whole data model. It's making it much more complicated then it needs to be (as you've found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should reduce the number of Optionals in the system. There are various ways to deal with Optional-collections (mutating helper methods like you suggested for instance), but Optional-overuse creates a lot of unneeded complexity. It is very rare that a Collection of any kind should be an Optional. That only makes sense if `nil` and "empty" mean different things (and that is very rare).

Rather that wrapping the entire data model around a specific JSON API, convert the JSON into the data model you want. For example, here is a JSON model that includes a required Int and may or may not include an Array, but internally we want to treat "missing array" as "empty." We also want to strip empty arrays before sending them.

```
import Foundation

let json = Data("""
{
    "y": 1
}
""".utf8)

struct X {
    var y: Int
    var z: [String]
}

extension X: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case y, z
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        y = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .y)
        z = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .z) ?? []
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(y, forKey: .y)
        if !z.isEmpty {
            try container.encode(z, forKey: .z)
        }
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
print(try decoder.decode(X.self, from: json))

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
print(String(data: try encoder.encode(X(y: 1, z: [])), encoding: .utf8)!)
```

This moves all the work into two methods rather than spreading it out all over the program every time you access the data model. Custom codables are still a bit tedious to write (and can introduce subtle bugs in the encoder step), so if you have a lot of them you should look at [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen/) which can write them for you.

If you really wanted to keep track of whether a key were missing versus empty (so you might re-encode the same way it was sent to you), then I would probably shadow the optional properties this way:

```
struct X: Codable{
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case y
        case _z = "z"
    }

    var y: Int
    private var _z: [String]?  // The actual `z` we got from the JSON
    var z: [String] { get { return _z ?? [] } set { _z = newValue } }

    init(y: Int, z: [String]?) {
        self.y = y
        self._z = z
    }
}
```

The "real" `z` is stored in `_z` and is available to be reserialized, but the rest of the program never sees an Optional.

Another somewhat common technique is to create an Adapter layer that converts a "JSON-compatible" struct to an internal data model and back. This allows your internal data model to be slightly different than the JSON if that's convenient.

You also can of course create helper methods, but the real key to all of this is to not allow Optionals to leak into the rest of your program that aren't really optional. If there must be complexity somewhere in the system, put it at the point of parsing/encoding, not at the point of use.

Answer (score 0):

You can always give initial value for optionals as well, just try declaring array like `var array: [Element]? = []` this way you don't have to check for nil value. You can use dynamic binding for using other conditions